# UnixODBC Cannot Query Pervasive SQL Database

Tags: freetds, unixodbc, pervasive-sql

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on a VM to try and connect to a Pervasive SQL (V12) database hosted on a Windows 10 machine.

I have tested the networking and I can telnet into the pervasive server with:

```
telnet 192.168.0.2 1583
```

But when it comes to using isql/tsql/osql I just cannot get a connection to the Pervasive server so that I can query the database.

I have spent four weeks on this and gotten to the point now where it almost works.

So when running this command in terminal:

```
root@test.dev:~# TDSDUMPCONFIG=stderr TDSDUMP=stderr tsql -S PSQL -U admin -P MASTER
```

I get the following output:

```
log.c:167:Starting log file for FreeTDS 0.95.95
    on 2016-05-20 10:11:02 with debug flags 0x4fff.
config.c:168:Getting connection information for [PSQL].
config.c:172:Attempting to read conf files.
config.c:353:... $FREETDSCONF not set.  Trying $FREETDS/etc.
config.c:366:... $FREETDS not set.  Trying $HOME.
config.c:296:Found conf file '/root/.freetds.conf' (.freetds.conf).
config.c:495:Looking for section global.
config.c:554:   Found section global.
config.c:557:Got a match.
config.c:580:   tds version = '4.2'
config.c:886:Setting tds version to 4.2 (0x402).
config.c:580:   dump file = '/tmp/freetds.log'
config.c:580:   timeout = '10'
config.c:580:   connect timeout = '10'
config.c:580:   text size = '64512'
config.c:554:   Found section psql.
config.c:568:   Reached EOF
config.c:495:Looking for section PSQL.
config.c:554:   Found section global.
config.c:554:   Found section psql.
config.c:557:Got a match.
config.c:580:   host = '192.168.0.2'
config.c:617:Found host entry 192.168.0.2 
config.c:620:IP addr is 192.168.0.2.
config.c:580:   port = '1583'
config.c:580:   client charset = 'UTF-8'
config.c:635:tds_parse_conf_section: client charset is UTF-8.
config.c:580:   tds version = '5.0'
config.c:886:Setting tds version to 5.0 (0x500).
config.c:568:   Reached EOF
config.c:300:Success: [PSQL] defined in /root/.freetds.conf.
config.c:765:Setting 'dump_file' to 'stderr' from $TDSDUMP.
config.c:213:Final connection parameters:
config.c:214:            server_name = PSQL
config.c:215:       server_host_name = 192.168.0.2
config.c:218:                ip_addr = 192.168.0.2
config.c:223:          instance_name = 
config.c:224:                   port = 1583
config.c:225:          major_version = 5
config.c:226:          minor_version = 0
config.c:227:             block_size = 0
config.c:228:               language = us_english
config.c:229:         server_charset = 
config.c:230:        connect_timeout = 10
config.c:231:       client_host_name = sails.dev
config.c:232:         client_charset = UTF-8
config.c:233:              use_utf16 = 0
config.c:234:               app_name = TSQL
config.c:235:              user_name = admin
config.c:238:                library = TDS-Library
config.c:239:              bulk_copy = 0
config.c:240:      suppress_language = 0
config.c:241:          encrypt level = 0
config.c:242:          query_timeout = 10
config.c:245:               database = 
config.c:246:              dump_file = stderr
config.c:247:            debug_flags = 0
config.c:248:              text_size = 64512
config.c:249:     emul_little_endian = 0
config.c:250:      server_realm_name = 
config.c:251:             server_spn = 
config.c:252:                 cafile = 
config.c:253:                crlfile = 
config.c:254:     check_ssl_hostname = 1
log.c:167:Starting log file for FreeTDS 0.95.95
    on 2016-05-20 10:11:02 with debug flags 0x4fff.
locale is "en_ZA.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
iconv.c:328:tds_iconv_open(0x641370, UTF-8)
iconv.c:187:local name for ISO-8859-1 is ISO-8859-1
iconv.c:187:local name for UTF-8 is UTF-8
iconv.c:187:local name for UCS-2LE is UCS-2LE
iconv.c:187:local name for UCS-2BE is UCS-2BE
iconv.c:346:setting up conversions for client charset "UTF-8"
iconv.c:348:preparing iconv for "UTF-8" <-> "UCS-2LE" conversion
iconv.c:395:preparing iconv for "ISO-8859-1" <-> "ISO-8859-1" conversion
iconv.c:400:tds_iconv_open: done
net.c:202:Connecting to 192.168.0.2 port 1583 (TDS version 5.0)
net.c:275:tds_open_socket: connect(2) returned "Operation now in progress"
net.c:314:tds_open_socket() succeeded
packet.c:740:Sending packet
0000 02 00 02 00 00 00 00 00-73 61 69 6c 73 2e 64 65 |........ sails.de|
0010 76 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |v....... ........|
0020 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 61-64 6d 69 6e 00 00 00 00 |.......a dmin....|
0030 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
0040 00 00 00 00 00 05 4d 41-53 54 45 52 00 00 00 00 |......MA STER....|
0050 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
0060 00 00 00 00 06 36 32 33-33 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |.....623 3.......|
0070 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
0080 00 00 00 04 03 01 06 0a-09 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
0090 00 00 00 00 54 53 51 4c-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |....TSQL ........|
00a0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
00b0 00 00 04 50 53 51 4c 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |...PSQL. ........|
00c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
00d0 00 04 00 06 4d 41 53 54-45 52 00 00 00 00 00 00 |....MAST ER......|
00e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
00f0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
0100 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
0110 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
0120 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
0130 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
0140 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
0150 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
0160 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
0170 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
0180 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
0190 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
01a0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
01b0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
01c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
01d0 00 08 05 00 00 00 54 44-53 2d 4c 69 62 72 61 72 |......TD S-Librar|
01e0 0a 05 00 00 00 00 0d 11-75 73 5f 65 6e 67 6c 69 |........ us_engli|
01f0 73 68 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |sh...... ........|

packet.c:740:Sending packet
0000 02 01 00 65 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 0a 00 |...e.... ........|
0010 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
0020 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........ ........|
0030 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 01 35 31 32 |........ .....512|
0040 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00-e2 1a 00 01 0b 08 00 01 |........ ........|
0050 e8 0f 6d 7f ff ff ff fe-02 0b 00 00 00 00 00 00 |..m..... ........|
0060 02 68 00 00 00         -                        |.h...|

token.c:327:tds_process_login_tokens()
query.c:3772:tds_disconnect() 
mem.c:648:tds_free_all_results()
util.c:165:Changed query state from IDLE to WRITING
util.c:165:Changed query state from WRITING to PENDING
packet.c:740:Sending packet
0000 0f 01 00 0a 00 00 00 00-71 00                   |........ q.|

token.c:550:tds_process_tokens(0x641370, 0x7ffee7182238, 0x7ffee718223c, 0x100)
util.c:165:Changed query state from PENDING to READING
query.c:3772:tds_disconnect() 
util.c:165:Changed query state from READING to DEAD
token.c:565:processing result tokens.  marker is  0()
token.c:116:tds_process_default_tokens() marker is 0()
token.c:119:leaving tds_process_default_tokens() connection dead
util.c:83:logic error: cannot change query state from DEAD to PENDING
util.c:165:Changed query state from DEAD to DEAD
util.c:322:tdserror(0x63f400, 0x641370, 20056, 9)
util.c:358:tdserror: client library not called because either tds_ctx (0x63f400) or tds_ctx->err_handler is NULL
util.c:375:tdserror: returning TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
token.c:336:looking for login token, got  0()
token.c:116:tds_process_default_tokens() marker is 0()
token.c:119:leaving tds_process_default_tokens() connection dead
login.c:472:login packet accepted
util.c:322:tdserror(0x63f400, 0x641370, 20002, 0)
util.c:358:tdserror: client library not called because either tds_ctx (0x63f400) or tds_ctx->err_handler is NULL
util.c:375:tdserror: returning TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
mem.c:648:tds_free_all_results()
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

And I have no idea what to try next so that I can query the data in the database.

I have tried all tds versions, tds drivers and pervasive ODBC drivers to no avail.

Any insight into what can be acertained from the above log and/or what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Did you create a ClientDSN on the Linux box (http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv12/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=uguide/unixsupp.8.13.html#68699)?  What edition (workgroup / server) of PSQL are you using on the WIndows machine? What error do you get using isql?

Comment: I have created a ClientDSN. On the Windows machine I'm using PSQL Server V12.00.160. When using isql I get;

    IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
    [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

Comment: Are you using the isql from the /usr/local/psql/bin?  Does it work if you use the psql user? If it works using psql but not other users, check out http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=getstart/unixappconf.15.3.html#80599

Comment: @mirtheil You are an absolute legend!!! I managed to query the db as the psql user! I cannot express how grateful I am for your help! Thank you!!! I have been trying for a while now following the guide you linked to, so I have created a new account and added this account to the pvsw group, set the enviroment variables but when I try isql on the new user account I get `[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/psql/lib64/libodbcci.so' : file not found`. This is odd because the file exists at this location. Any ideas what could be the cause of this?

Comment: @mirtheil I came right! Ended up having to copy the contents of the `/home/psql/.bashrc` to `/root/.bashrc` and then all the users could connect. Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a ClientDSN usind `dsnadd` ([docs](http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv12/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=uguide/unixsupp.8.13.html#68699)).

Once the DSN is set up,  test using the `psql` user and `isql` and then follow the instructions for "[Using Utilities from Users Other than psql](http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv11/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=getstart/unixappconf.15.3.html#80599)" for using another user.  As noted in comments, copy the contents of `/home/psql/.bashrc` to the `/root/.bashrc`.